# Is there a reason why there is a question mark in front of the initial php tag? i.e. <?php

Tags: php

The question says it all. I'd like to know if it has any special meaning other than the creators of php making you put a ? in there.

Comment: Well there has to be something. How else can you differentiate a tag such as `<php` from something such as `<img`?

Comment: I found this question useful to discover why <?php instead of <? was used. I figured php was an application name and it could be anything that would consume the content (like if there was a Java program on the server to spit out HTML you could theoretically define <?java).

Answer (score 11):

The `<?php ... ?>` syntax that you're referring to is actually an XML style [processing instruction](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi) with a target of `php`:

> [Definition: Processing instructions (PIs) allow documents to contain instructions for applications.]
>   [...]
>   The PI begins with a target (PITarget) used to identify the application to which the instruction is directed.

So it is actually standard syntax for embedding code inside an XML or HTML document. Similarly, you'll see things like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```